# Eclipse Juno to Photon formatting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

I'm switching to Eclipse Photon from Juno. The SVN code is formatted using a profile that I imported in both Photon and Eclipse.
The max line width is set to 150 in both Photon and Juno.
The problem I'm having, after sync-ing the Identation, Line wrapping settings and such is that when I save and Eclipse does an auto-format the Juno version breaks the line like this:
[image]

while Photon breaks it like this:

[image]

I'm having a hard time finding out what setting controls this behavior thus any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse Photon is now 8 releases old, why are you using such an old release?

Comment: I'll switch to latest if that will fix my formatting issue but I do doubt that.